# Are numbers represented directly as bits?

Tags: memory, binary

I know a string value, is converted to a numeric representation and that is what the computer sees.

How about values that are already numeric?

So if I have a value of integer 128 and I store it in a variable that should hold unsigned integer. Am I certain the actual value the computer sees is `0b10000000`?

I mean will numeric value map directly to their binary values?